# How do I do this array indexing in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Given an index array `I`, how to I set the values of a data array `D` whose indices don't exist in `I`?

Example: How to I get `A` from `I` and `D`?

```
I = array( [[1,1], [2,2], [3,3]] )

D = array( [[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            [ 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3],
            [ 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
            [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
            [ 7, 8, 9, 1, 2, 3]] )

A = array( [[ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [ 0, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0],
            [ 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0],
            [ 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]] )
```

Edit: I'm looking for how to do this in one shot for cases where `I` and `d` are big.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple solution:

```
A = zeros(D.shape)
for i, j in I:
    A[i, j] = D[i, j]
```

Vectorized:

```
A = zeros(D.shape)
i, j = I.T
A[i, j] = D[i, j]
```

Comment: Is there a proper vectorized way to do it? Both `D` and `A` will be large, so I'm afraid this in an inefficient way to go about it.

Comment: @ajwood: figured out and posted the vectorized version.